# Browser detection using Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-detection

I have this code:

```
<body onload="detect(navigator.appName)">
<h2 id=alert>This tutorial is for Google Chrome users,
why would you want to read it?</h2>
</body>
<script>
function detect(x){
    alert(x)
    if (x != "Chrome"){
        document.getElementById("alert").style.display = '';
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is, whenever I open the page using **Google Chrome**, It returns "*Netscape*". Is there a workaround?

[Webpage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38516275/MyWebPage/FPP/Chrome_and_flash.html)

Comment: Because I'm on my phone that doesn't have chrome

Comment: Good way to cut your audience down.

Comment: What else have you tried?  Also, what were you expecting to be returned?

Comment: @j08691 It says in his code that it's a tutorial for Google Chrome users. Why bash him for asking a question that targets a specific browser?

Comment: @Samuel - yes I realize that, however as Esailija noted, what if I have Chrome but might not have access to it at the moment?

Comment: @j08691 See [Webpage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38516275/MyWebPage/FPP/Chrome_and_flash.html). It will not remove any info from the page, only it will display the message, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On chrome this is what `navigator.appName` will give you:

> Netscape

It will be much easier if you parse the User Agent

```
if ( ! /(Chrome)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = '';
}
```

But i have to say, if you show your tutorial to only those who are using Chrome, you are missing the point of the internet.

Comment: `if (/(Chrome)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.getElementById("alert").style.display = '';
    }`

Comment: Hiding content with JS will still show the content until the script is loaded. I would suggest hiding it with CSS and then show it if the conditions aren't met.

Comment: @JDavis There's actually a `style="display:none;"` attached to the `<h2>` in the final code, I removed it here because it's not a neccesity.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery's browser function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/. It's tested and true.

Comment: I'm not into jQuery that much.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery question.  There's no jQuery tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just because there is no tag doesn't mean it can't be suggested.

Comment: The general protocol here on StackOverflow is that you only propose a solution using a library such as JQuery, Prototype, YUI, etc... if that is asked for in the question.  Otherwise, plain javascript solutions should be offered or you should use a comment on the question to ask for clarification about the desired for answers using a library.

Comment: What if OP had never heard of jQuery? I think he would be pretty happy to discover it. Or if somebody searches for this question they'll have the tip to use jQuery. The OP can decide which is the right answer.

Comment: @Samuel I have heard of jQuery, I just don't feel like learning it if I don't necessarily need it.